# a good sample on dec atomic operation on floating field

Tags: mongoengine

Is mongoengine broken for atomic dec operation a FloatField or DecimalField?

Here is what i am trying -

```
class Account (DynamicDocument): 
user = ReferenceField(User,passthrough=True,reverse_delete_rule=True,required=True,unique=True)
amount = FloatField(min_value=0,required=True)
```

::::

Now I am trying to perform a atomic "dec" operation. The "amnt" value is passed as 10

```
 Account.objects(user=usr).update(dec__amount=amnt)
```

However, I am getting error - mongoengine.error.ValidationError: Float value is too small. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Locate the issue -  **min_value=0** is the culprit. Removing this, it started working again. Not sure, why this is the issue? I thought this is a value constrain to the column